# How to Inject a class in JUnit Test with Dagger2

Tags: java, junit, dagger-2

I've been following CoffeeMaker tutorial [here](http://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide). Right now I don't want to override any modules/components in my test but want to inject a Class ElectricHeater into my JUnit Test.

When I do so I get a NullPointerExeception when I invoke heater.on(); Not sure what I'm missing.

Here is the test code.

```
package coffee;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public final class CoffeeMakerTest {

  @Inject
  Heater heater;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setUp() {
    CoffeeComponent coffeeComponent = DaggerCoffeeComponent.builder().
    build();

  }

  @Test
  public void testCoffeeMaker() throws Exception {
    heater.on();
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't said if this is maven, gradle, or other ... but regardless, would you mind including a sample of your build script? The dagger guide explicitly says "[Don't use dagger for unit testing](http://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html#dont-use-dagger-for-unit-testing)", but since it's a compile-time injection framework, I really think it should be possible, probably with a tweak of your build script.

Comment: Its other internal build which I cannot share. Yes I know Dagger is not meant for unit testing. I was simply trying to inject some class in JUnit for integration testing framework I'm planning to write to test if that would work.   However I found the answer how I could get this working, see below.

Comment: Noticed your two comments above. Does this still hold true? I don't see anything that says "Don't use dagger for unit testing". (I can't even understand why it would be a bad idea tbh.)

Answer (score -1):

Modified code

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { DripCoffeeModule.class })
public interface CoffeeComponent {
  CoffeeMaker maker();

  void inject(CoffeeMakerTest coffeeMaker);
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
  CoffeeComponent coffeeComponent = DaggerCoffeeComponent.builder().build();
  coffeeComponent.inject(this);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed without.